# Generate a PointCloud object in Open3D from RealSense data

Tags: python, realsense, open3d, rosbag

I'm trying to convert data captured from an Intel RealSense device into an Open3D PointCloud object that I then need to process. For the moment I only have the [rosbag sample files](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/sample-data.md) to work with, but I think a similar procedure should be used with the direct stream from the device. So far I managed to read and display the files using [pyrealsense2](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/python) and OpenCV.

Now I'm trying to use Open3D. For example (using the [Structured Light Short-Range Example](https://librealsense.intel.com/rs-tests/TestData/structured.bag)):

```
import open3d as o3d

bag_reader = o3d.t.io.RSBagReader()
bag_reader.open("structured.bag")

rgbd_image = bag_reader.next_frame()
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(
    rgbd_image,
    o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(
        o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsicParameters.PrimeSenseDefault)))
```

This results in an error saying:

```
TypeError: create_from_rgbd_image(): incompatible function arguments.
```

So I tried to create a `Open3D.geometry.RGBDImage` manually with the "correct" format:

```
import numpy as np

raw_rgb = np.array(rgbd_image.color)
raw_depth = np.array(rgbd_image.depth)
new_rgbd_image = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(
    o3d.geometry.Image(raw_rgb), o3d.geometry.Image(raw_depth))
```

Now there is no TypeError when creating the PointCloud, but it's completely wrong, in fact it shows like this:

```
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

[image: Front View]
[image: Side View]

When in reality it should look something like this (notice I'm just elaborating the first frame when actually the rosbag file is a video):

[image: Correct]

I also tried to mess around with the intrinsic and extrinsic matrixes using the parameters extracted from the rosbag file but still the point cloud looks really messed up.

What am I doing wrong? What's the way to correctly recreate a point cloud in Open3D from RealSense data?

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter the same problem: The point is that functions from different branches are used here, one from Legacy, the other from Tensor. In this case used o3d**.t.**io + o3d.geometry. You need to use either o3d.io + o3d.geometry, or o3d.t.io + o3d.t.geometry. Another option is using to_legacy()/from_legacy() with Tensor data.